# Apache 2 ProxyPass Only The Homepage And Not Other URLS

Tags: apache-2.2

I have Laravel and Nuxt hosted on example.com

Nuxt running on port e.g example.com:3001

Laravel apis working on example.com/api/{dynamic}

Now I'm want to render homepage only on Nuxt and I tried following:

```
ServerName example.com

ProxyPreserveHost On


ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3001/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3001/
```

But its proxying the API endpoints as well. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Two things to keep in mind for [`ProxyPass`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) :

## Excluding sub-directories

The `!` directive is used in situations where you don't want to reverse-proxy a subdirectory / location.

```
ProxyPass "/api/"    "!"
```

## Ordering `ProxyPass` Directives

The configured `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassMatch` rules are checked in the order of configuration. The first rule that matches wins.

---

So to completely exclude all the `/api/*` subdirectories from getting included in the reverse proxy definition for the `/` root , the exclude for `/api` needs to defined **first**

```
ProxyPass "/api/"    "!"
ProxyPass "/"        "http://127.0.0.1:3001/"
ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://127.0.0.1:3001/"
```

Or a slightly more complex with several additional API's all on different end-points:

```
ProxyPass "/api/demo/" "http://demo.example.com:3002/"
ProxyPassReverse "/api/demo/" "http://demo.example.com:3002/"
ProxyPass "/api/test/" "http://test.example.com:8080/"
ProxyPassReverse "/api/test/" "http://test.example.com:8080/"
ProxyPass "/api/"    "!"
ProxyPass "/"        "http://127.0.0.1:3001/"
ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://127.0.0.1:3001/"
```

Comment: No need to quote every single parameter